# integer pair add to hashset java

Tags: java, hashset

I set the integer pair class as below:

```
public class pair{
    int a;
    int b;
    pair(int p,int q){
        this.a=p;
        this.b=q;
    }
}
```

When I add them into hashset, there are no duplicates:

```
HashSet<pair> set=new HashSet<pair>();
        pair temp=new pair(3,5);
        set.add(temp);
        pair temp1=new pair(3,5);
        set.add(temp1);
        for(pair p:set){
            System.out.println(p.a+"  "+p.b);
        }
```

But it gives me this output:

```
3  5
3  5
```

What should I edit to have no duplicate in the hashset?

Comment: override hashCode() method

Answer (score 10):

You must do two things:

1. Override `equals()`
2. Override `hashCode()`

As the javadoc for `hashCode()` tells you, it must agree with `equals()`, ie if two objects are equals, they should have the same hashCode. It's ok for two objects that are not equal to have the same hashCode,

Something like this:

```
public class pair{
    int a;
    int b;
    pair(int p,int q){
        a=p;
        b=q;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Pair) {
            Pair p = (Pair)o;
            return p.a == a && p.b == b;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Integer(a).hashCode() * 31 + new Integer(b).hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: why  multiply by 31?

Comment: @jamarcus_13 it can be anything, but 31 is commonly chosen because it’s a [Mersenne prime](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), not too big (doesn’t aggressively overflow `int`) and not too small (yields reasonable “smearing” of the hash across several bit positions, all of 31’s used bits being `1`).

Comment: Although, it can be any number like in this example here.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90932/print-the-number-of-unique-pairs-stored-in-a-hashset

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the **equals** method of your **pair** class to specifically look at each pair and see if they match.

EDIT: Yes and the **hashcode** method must be overidden as well

Answer (score 2):

you should override both `hashCode` and `equals` method of the class for this to work. This is done to honour the hashCode and equals contract of an object in Java.